# CVX - matlab - nonlinear constraints

Tags: matlab, cvx

In FMINCON, nonlinear constraints can be provided as a function argument (nonlcon). I tried to use a similar method in CVX

```
cvx_begin
   variable x(n)
   minimize( somefunc(x))
   subject to
      nonlcon(x)
cvx_end
```

But I get an error:

```
Disciplined convex programming error:
Cannot perform the operation: {real affine} ./ {real affine}
```

In the nonlcon, there is an element-wise division operation. It gives the error at that line and I can't change the constraint to any other way. Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: `cvxopt` is python, not Matlab, correct? If so, your question is tagged wrong.

Comment: @horchler No, it's matlab. There are two different codes. I'm talking about this one: (http://cvxr.com/cvx/)

Comment: I think I should have said CVX instead of CVXOPT, You're right.

Comment: @horchler Actually I have made some progress and now my error is regarding mtimes in cvx. Is there no way to do a vector x vector in cvx?

Comment: Wow, that's in Matlab? Well, it looks like they're doing a lot of stuff to support this very un-Matlab-like "modeling syntax". I wouldn't be surprised if they haven't bothered to figure out how to support Matlab's native functions and vectorization. I'm guessing that you'll get much better support in [their forums](http://ask.cvxr.com/questions/) than here.

Comment: I have already posted there. There are, like, 3 people who are active in that forum. So, not gonna have much luck there.